# Angular URL does not work in build project but it works on localhost:4200

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

When I open a sub URL it works on my local environment like `http://localhost:4200/login`. But after I build the project with `ng build --prod` all sub URLs are not working on the live server.

If I open a sub URL using `this.router.navigate(['/system']);` it works in the built project but if I reload that same URL it does not work (404).

Is  there any issue with my Routing Strategies?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {SystemComponent} from './components/system/system.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AdminComponent} from './components/admin/admin.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent}, // home pages
    {path: 'login', component: HomeComponent},// sub page 1
    {path: 'system', component: SystemComponent}, // sub page 2
    {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent} //sub page 3
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        SystemComponent,
        AdminComponent
    ],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes,
        {enableTracing: true},// <-- debugging purposes only it will show  big  console  log  data
        {useHash: true}  ),
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: On Index.html file , you may need edit <base href="/your_web_folder_on_server">

Comment: @everyBit my project  not in  server  folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found  solution  to  my error  it's with  my **.htaccess** file.
Here  the   links that help me to solve  this error.

[HOWTOs / Making sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are working as they should](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.6/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works)

- Update  your   virtual host files  `sudo nano
  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
- Add  below  code under `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`

```html
    <Directory /var/www/html/projectFolder>
       # Don't show directory index
       Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
          
       # Allow .htaccess files
        AllowOverride All
          
       # Allow web access to this directory
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

- Then restart  server

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have set the base href in `index.html`

You could also use the commands below to update them if required.

`ng build --base-href /`

or `ng build --bh /`

or `ng build --prod --bh /`

This overrides the base href set in index.html and sets it if it is not set. Set it according to the deployment and modify accordingly. Can't comment since I am not familiar with your deployment strategy

You may also be interested in the `--deploy-url` option if you have different folder for assets
refer [ https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/06/angular-4-use-of-base-href-and-deploy-url-build-options/ ]

Comment: Yes  sir  i add it as Answers.

Comment: @SupunAbesekara consider clicking on the `grey tick icon` below the votes so that it becomes accepted and others refering with same issue can find it useful.